# How do I assign a variable to a specific element in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, frameworks

I'd like to access a certain value in my array that is assigned to run a particular part of my code. For example if my array consists of numbers 1 to 6 where each number is assigned to a variable that inputed via the keyboard the variable runs part of my code how would I implement this? So far I have only got to...

```
public class yTerminal {
public static void main(String[] args)
{               
    screen.println("Press key to access function: ");
    screen.println("1 - Open \n2 - Close \n3 - Help \n" 
    + "4 - Internet \n5 - Call \n6 "
    + "- Go");

    int[] numberInput = new int[5];
    int i;
    for (i=1; i < 7; i++)
        numberInput[i] = keyboard.readInt("Enter key corresponding to function: ");     

}
```

}

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but it sounds like you want a Map. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Comment: sounds like he can use a switch case method over the input to run some methods

Comment: Note that in Java arrays are numbered from zero. Your `for` loop counts from 1 to 6 on a 5-element array; you should count from `i = 0` to `i < numberInput.length` instead.

Comment: I think you're asking the wrong questions. It's okay that you tell us what your attempt was, but the question is more geared to picking one of a users inputs, than it is: `assign a variable to a specific element in an array?`

Comment: Do you want to have 6 Keyboard inputs? Or only one Number between 1 and 6? If so, you won't need an array. Btw number_input[i] = ... will cause a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for i > 4

Comment: Thanks but I'm trying to access the stored value in the array e.g. 2 when the user inputs the number 2 when prompted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this would be a better implementation rather than using an array...

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int choice;
while(true){
     System.out.print("Enter key to access functions:");
     choice = sc.nextInt();
     switch(choice) {
     case(1):
          do function:open;
          break;
     case(2):
          do function:close;
          break;
     case(3):
          do function:help;
          break;
     case(4):
          do function:internet;
          break:
     case(5):
          do function:call;
          break;
     case(6):
          do function:go;
          break;
     default:
          System.out.println("Invalid Input");
          break;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of concepts -

1) Reading user input. You can use [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to get the user input via keyboard.

```
for eg.
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter key corresponding to function: ");
```

2) To call respective piece of code according to user input. [Switch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) case would work best.

```
switch(reader.nextInt()) {
    case '<whatever_number>': 
    // your piece of code. 
    break;
}
```